Flutter app login issue on specific Samsung devices despite successful testing
I'm encountering an unusual issue with login functionality in my Flutter app, specifically on certain Samsung devices. Despite thorough testing on multiple Android (Realme, Redmi, Pixel, Samsung, Moto) and iOS models, login works flawlessly on my end. However, some users are reporting login failures exclusively on Samsung devices.
Here are some key details:

Testing: I've personally tested the login functionality on various Samsung devices available to me, including the Samsung M12 with One UI 4.2 and Android 12, and haven't encountered any issues.

User Reports: Several users, particularly those using Samsung devices, have reported login failures. One user I spoke with is using a Samsung M12 with One UI 4.2 and Android 12, and they consistently experience login failures despite the app functioning correctly on my identical test device.

Troubleshooting Attempts: I've checked network connectivity, backend services, app permissions, and configurations, but haven't been able to identify any issues that could explain the discrepancy between my testing results and user reports.


Has anyone encountered a similar issue with login failures specifically on Samsung devices, even after successful testing on similar models? Are there any known device-specific factors or troubleshooting steps I might be overlooking that could help resolve this discrepancy?
I found this on GitHub (something like I'm facing), but it's an old and not have any solution.
Link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43257
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

can you put your Http log here? What is the issue when API is called?
Run your app in release mode on a Samsung testing device are you able to reproduce the issue?
Yes also please check all the manifest file they contain internet permission or not?

I've tried reproducing the issue by using the same device with same android version and oneui version that one user reported, but on my side app is working well so there is not any issue while testing, but lots of samsung users are reporting the login failure issue mostly samsung M series and S23 series.
You can refer to this link (this is an old issue but can help)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43257

If you are using firebase for login functionality so you need to do the following:

Enable App Check in firebase
If you publish app already to play store, so get your SHA-1, and SHA-256 keys from there, and put those in firebase project.
If you havent publish app yet to playstore, so you need to do the following: goto android folder and run ./gradlew signingReport, get sha keys and place in firebase

if you still face issue, feel free to ask, and share some more details about issue, like what type of login are you implementing, which package are you using etc.
Thanks

Hi, thanks for replying.. My app isn't using Firebase, I've spring boot rest API on my server side and app sends request to the server to authenticate login credentials. My app is already available on play/app store
